# How to copy text on Android like on a computer?

Tags: copy-paste

I want to copy a string of text from an ASCII text generator, but whenever I paste the art, it turns into a line of text.

Example:

```
_ _ _ ___ ___ _ __ ___ ___ _ __ __ _ _ __ __| | ___ _ __ ___ | |_ _____ _| |_ / __|/ _ \| '_ ` _ \ / _ \ | '__/ _` | '_ \ / _` |/ _ \| '_ ` _ \ | __/ _ \ \/ / __| \__ \ (_) | | | | | | __/ | | | (_| | | | | (_| | (_) | | | | | | | || __/> <| |_ |___/\___/|_| |_| |_|\___| |_| \__,_|_| |_|\__,_|\___/|_| |_| |_| \__\___/_/\_\\__|
```

(This should say "some random text")

What I want it to look like:
[image: screenshot]

It seems that when I copy the art, it automatically cuts out spaces and line breaks. Is there a way I can resolve this? Getting the art to paste properly is important for an upcoming project.

Edit: I am copying from Google Chrome into DroidEdit.

Comment: Possibly this is something to do with one of the apps you're using. Could you [edit] your question and name what app you're pasting from, and pasting into?

Comment: Do you take the width of screen into account?